# error in two dimensional secand method

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

i want to understand what is a error in the following code?code is given below

```
function x0=secand2d(f,g,x,dx,tol)
% find solution of f(x,y)=0 and g(x,y)=0
for i=1:20
    x0=x;
    f0=[feval(f,x0),feval(g,x0)];
   x0=x+[dx(1),0];
   fx=[feval(f,x0),feval(g,x0)];
   fx=(fx-f0)/dx(1);
   x0=x+[0 dx(2)];
   fy=[feval(f,x0),feval(g,x0)];
   fy=(fy-f0)/dx(2);
   A=[fx;fy]+eps;
   x=x+dx;
   dx=(-A\f0'-dx')';
   if(norm(dx)<tol) ;return; end;
end;

 disp(norm(dx));
 pause;

end
```

which represents of two dimensional secant method,where function f and g is defined  by following form

```
f=@(x,y) (x-sin(x+y)); and   g=@(x,y) y-cos(x-y);
```

i have also checked and  these to function works  fine on it's parameters

```
f(3,3)

ans =

    3.2794
```

and

```
g(1,1)

ans =

     0
```

also

```
x=[0.9 0.9];
dx=[0.1 0.1];
tol=1e-5;
```

but following code   generated such kind of errors

```
secand2d(f,g,x,dx,tol)
Error using @(x,y)(x-sin(x+y))
Not enough input arguments.

Error in secand2d (line 5)
    f0=[feval(f,x0),feval(g,x0)];
```

please help me to clarify  reasons of this errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are passing only `x0` to `f` here:

```
f0=[feval(f,x0),feval(g,x0)];
```

`f` and `g` are expecting two inputs. You can fix the error like this:

```
f0=[feval(f,x0,y0),feval(g,x0,y0)];
```

If there is not a particular reason you are using `feval` you can do it like this:

```
f0 = [f(x0, y0) g(x0, y0)];
```

Comment: but x0 contains two parameter

Comment: Do you mean it is a vector like `x0=[x0_1 x0_2]`?

Comment: No, I am afraid it is not. You can do `f0 = [f(x0(1), x0(2)) g(x0(1), x0(2))];`

Comment: yes this is what i have done,thanks very much,i am using this book http://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Methods-MATLAB%C2%AB-Engineers-Scientists/dp/0534938221/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1368103039&sr=8-8&keywords=numerical+methods+with+matlab

Comment: Yeah, the reviews are quite bad. Use the examples with caution :)